# Segmentation fault while using strcpy()?

Tags: c, linux, strcpy

I have a global structure:

```
struct thread_data{
   char *incall[10];
   int syscall arg_no;
   int client_socket;
};
```

and in main()

```
char buffer[256];
char *incall[10];
struct thread_data arg_to_thread;

strcpy(incall[0],buffer);   /*works fine*/
strcpy(arg_to_thread.incall[0],buffer); /*causes segmentation fault*/
```

Why does this happen and Please suggest a way out.

thanks

Comment: where are you allocating memory to store those strings?

Comment: won't it automatically store in stack

Comment: no, all that's allocated is 10 pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A segfault means that something is wrong. But *no* segfault does not mean that something *isn't* wrong. If two situations are basically the same, and one segfaults and the other does not, it usually means that they are *both* wrong, but only one of them happens to be triggering the segfault.

Looking at the line `char* incall[10]`, what that means is you have an array of 10 pointers to a char. By default, these pointers will be pointing at random places. Therefore, strcpying into incall[0] will be copying the string to a random location. This is most likely going to segfault! You need to initialise incall[0] first (using `malloc`).

So a bigger question is why *doesn't* the first line segfault? I would imagine the reason is that it *just so happens* that whatever was in memory before was a valid pointer. Therefore, the strcpy doesn't segfault, it just overwrites something else which will later cause completely unexpected behaviour. So you must fix *both* lines of code.

Another issue (once you have fixed that) is that `strcpy` itself is highly dangerous -- since it copies strings until it finds a 0 byte and then stops, you can never be sure exactly how much it's going to copy (unless you use `strlen` to allocate the destination memory). So you should use `strncpy` instead, to limit the number of bytes copied to the size of the buffer.

Comment: 'Circumspect'? Perhaps you meant 'suspect' or 'dangerous' or ... If used by someone who knows what they're doing (which means, amongst other things, how long the source string is and how much space there is in the destination buffer), `strcpy()` is perfectly safe. Not everyone ensures that they are safe. (_There is an argument that if you know how long the strings are, you can use `memmove()`, or sometimes `memcpy()`, to do the string copy more efficiently._) Remember that `strncpy()` does not guarantee null termination of your strings. (Using `strncat()` is even more fraught with danger!)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler This is true, but I'm giving advice to someone who doesn't know what they're doing (and I did say "unless you use strlen to allocate the destination memory"). But that is a very good point about strncpy -- I'm not sure what is worse: overwriting the buffer, or having a non-null-terminated string. (I would still say the former is worse, so prefer strncpy over strcpy.)

Comment: It's tricky. The standard C string functions leave much to be desired (but they are standard, widely available, and can be used safely with care). The lack of null termination on a short copy is so serious that the other benefits of `strncpy()` are, IMNSHO, outweighed by the poor behaviour in the one case where you really need it to behave sensibly. I'd live with its zero padding if it guaranteed null termination. In its original application, not null terminating was a positive virtue, but that is ancient history now.  (It was designed to copy 14 character file names in directories on Unix.)

Answer (score 1):

You've not initialized the pointer `incall[0]`, so goodness only knows where the first `strcpy()` writes to.  You are unlucky that your program does not crash immediately.

You've not initialized the pointer `arg_to_thread.incall[0]`, so goodness only knows where the second `strcpy()` writes to.  You are lucky that your program crashes now, rather than later.

In neither case is it the compiler's fault; you must always ensure you initialize your pointers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have enough memory allocated for your string buffers.
2. Stay away from `strcpy`. Use `strncpy` instead. `strcpy` is a notorious source of buffer overflow vulnerabilities - a security and maintenance nightmare for which there really isn't an excuse.

Comment: Remember that `strncpy()` does not guarantee null termination of your strings if the source is too long.  It also guarantees null padding of your string if the source is shorter than the destination. (Using `strncat()` is even more fraught with danger!  What size do you specify in the length parameter?  The answer is _not_ the size of the target string!)

Comment: My point is, relying solely on the sentinel to determine the string length is fragile. Explicitly carrying string lengths around is not, even though you can of course still produce bugs.