# Initializing a pointer to structure of typedefs

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have read similar threads on SO on this topic ([How to initialize a Pointer to a struct in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709929/how-to-initialize-a-pointer-to-a-struct-in-c) and 
[Initializing a pointer to a structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296880/initializing-a-pointer-to-a-structure))
but failed trying `new` or `malloc`. I've got a bunch of `typedefs` like

```
typedef void  (*STP_CALLBACK_ON_TOPOLOGY_CHANGED)       (BRIDGE* bridge);
typedef void* (*STP_CALLBACK_ALLOC_AND_ZERO_MEMORY)     (unsigned int size);
typedef void  (*STP_CALLBACK_FREE_MEMORY)               (void* p);
typedef void  (*STP_CALLBACK_ENABLE_LEARNING)           (BRIDGE* bridge, unsigned int portIndex, unsigned int treeIndex, bool enable);
```

which form a structure

```
    struct STP_CALLBACKS
    {
      STP_CALLBACK_ON_TOPOLOGY_CHANGED      onTopologyChanged;
      STP_CALLBACK_ALLOC_AND_ZERO_MEMORY    allocAndZeroMemory;
      STP_CALLBACK_FREE_MEMORY              freeMemory;
      ...
    };
```

and when I want to init a pointer to this structure with

```
const STP_CALLBACKS *callbacks = new STP_CALLBACKS;
```

It actually inits nothing. I'm quite a newbie and obviously miss something important. What is a correct way to do it?

P.S. the code above is from [mstp-lib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mstp-lib/). I'm on VS2015.

Comment: They are function pointers....

Comment: What do you want to initialise them with?

Comment: @doctorlove to use within a next function - [STP_CreateBridge](https://sourceforge.net/p/mstp-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/_help/STP_CreateBridge.html)

Comment: You didn't tell it to initialise the contents. Since you declared it const, you'll have a hard time setting members unless you define a constructor. You don't need dynamic allocation. You just need to decide what functions to point at, or set them to nullptr.

Comment: I didn't ask why - I asked what. You need to tell it what the functions pointers should point to. If you show what functions you want it to point to, we can show you how.

Comment: I suggest that you take a pick from  [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause you are not actually initializing. Typedef just declares a type. All what `new` does above is allocating memory for 4 function pointers.
To initialize this memory you need constructor:

```
struct STP_CALLBACKS { 
    STP_CALLBACKS(STP_CALLBACK_ON_TOPOLOGY_CHANGED _fp1, ...
...
```

Then, having actual functions to be called like func1, func2, ... you can initialize your structure:

```
void func1(BRIDGE* bridge) {
   ...
}

STP_CALLBACKS callbacks(func1, ...
```

And then call back your functions:

```
BRIDGE bridge;
callbacks.onTopologyChanged(&bridge);
```